# Problem running ruby app under passenger with rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, rvm, bundler

I've switched a ruby app (using Thoth, which uses Ramaze in turn) over to work inside an rvm ruby@gemset combo, with bundler.  I can access the console version of it, so it's happy about what gems it has.  However, when i try and access it via the server, (via passenger under nginx) i get this error from passenger:

Could not find activesupport-2.3.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I don't understand this as i do have activesupport 2.3.8 installed in the app's gemset in rvm.  Perhaps passenger doesn't know about rvm, or know to use the right rvm?  I'm unsure how passenger hooks into my app, and whether it needs to know about the rvm for instance.  The only reference to passenger i have seen is in my nginx config block, where i say `passenger_enabled on;`

Has anyone else had problems of this nature?

max

EDIT:  some more details about my setup:

My app is in `/var/www/apps/akrotoski`
This is in a rvm/gemset called `ruby-1.8.7-p302@akrotoski`

It just occurred to me that this might be a problem with nginx running under root.  If i switch to root and do `echo $PATH` i get

`/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.01/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

If i `echo $PATH` in my app's rvm i get

`/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@akrotoski/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.01/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

So maybe nginx/passenger is running in such a way as to not be using the rvm?  Like i say i'm quite ignorant of how passenger actually hooks into an app in this way.

Comment: How are you starting passenger/nginx? What command are you using and what directory are you running it from?

Comment: Hi pan.  I'm starting nginx with `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`.  Because i have the passenger_enabled on; block in my nginx config for this app then it should pick it up automatically.  I can restart the passenger-enabled app with `touch tmp/restart.txt` in the application's root folder.  I'll add some more details to my OP about folders etc.

Comment: Did you install rvm as sudo and system-wide or just for a specific user?

Comment: Just for a specific user - i guess that was my mistake?  (see edit to OP).  I just switched to root and did 'rvm' and it didn't recognise the command.  There's a .bashrc hack you need to do to be able to use the rvm command `http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/comment-page-1/#comment-103` and i tried that in root's .bashrc and that didn't help.  So, i guess i screwed up.  What's the best way to fix this do you think, ie to give root access to rvm as well?  Should i just install it again as root?  Will that cause conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install RVM as root so that it is a system-wide install and it is installed in /usr/local/rvm:

```
sudo bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

You can read more [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) about the installation. Also, you'll want to ensure that your default rvm is the correct one for starting your nginx application. For example, you might want to do the following:

```
sudo rvm --default 1.8.7@akrotoski
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: cool - should i uninstall the rvm i installed under the 'deploy' user already do you think?

Comment: It might be a good idea, that way you ensure you are starting from a clean installation.

Comment: pan - i did the install as per the rvm home page (which is the same as you posted above minus sudo), while root, and followed the instruction about editing .bashrc (/root/.bashrc in this case) to add the extra last line.  But i still get `bash: rvm: command not found` back when i try to call rvm.  I also tried following your commands exactly, ie installing rvm with sudo, and setting a default rvm with sudo, and switching to that default with sudo.  Then did nginx restart, still exactly the same problem :(

Comment: In your passenger configuration which ruby is passenger pointing to? If you have this explicitly set you should probably remove this definition because it will override the system default. If it's not explicitly set, then try setting it to the ruby+gemset binary.

Comment: I put the rvm-installed version of ruby first in the path (not touching the passenger config, since it just uses the PATH anyway), and restarted nginx, and that's sorted it.  Thanks!  What happens, though, if i want to run multiple apps on the same box, each with their own version of ruby?

Comment: You'll probably want to direct passenger to use the different Ruby versions explicitly, rather than using PATH. If this is all for development then I would recommend using passenger standalone or a solution like pow rather than booting nginx and passenger to simply test code. This will give you the most flexibility since passenger standalone runs in the project directory and uses that rvm ruby and gemset.

Comment: This is for production, i'm mucking about with it on my staging server but at some point i plan on deploying various different apps on the staging server and would like to sandbox them all nicely each with their own rvm/gemset.  Can you have multiple passenger standalone instances?  I'll look into it.  Anyway thanks for all your help, off to have a beer now.  Cheers! max

Comment: You can have multiple standalone's running and bind them to different ports, but I would recommend just using nginx if it's for production. You'll probably have to find each app to a different port or subdomain though. Enjoy!